# Selenium RemoteWebDriver release session but don't close browser

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I am new to selenium automation testing, Is there a way to kill remotewebdriver session without closing the browser?

Also is it possible to wait for **user intervention** (say Click on certain element)

I googled my queries, but couldn't find any answer I was looking for.

**EDIT 1:**

I was doing a little POC on a customer relation service app, where csr will click a button and it will open an external application, and take him to a form, where some information will be populated automatically by selenium and some information will be populated by csr's manual input.

So far in the Project, I have a spring mvc 4 application. There is a REST controller. Upon posting a json to my controller, it call invokes a service method which opens selenium remote webdriver.

1.I want my browser to stay opened until user press submit button.

2.I want to take csr to the desired page and lose the control of selenium, afterwards csr will submit the page or close the browser depending on situation.

Comment: As far as I'm aware there's no way to kill the driver object, but leave the browser open, as it's the driver object that creates the browser.

You may be able to wait for user intervention if their interaction with the page changes the state of a field in some way, so you can check for their change in the code - though it kind of defeats the purpose of automated testing :) Can what you're expecting the user to do be passed in as runtime arguments?

Comment: Thanks @Josh , I have updated my question. Please check. Thank you

Comment: did you with reading an input from end user like Scanner in java, raw_input in python. they will wait till the user provides the input